# Can a type definition have a default value in Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, graphql, schema, gatsby

Reading the docs on [Customizing the GraphQL Schema](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions) I'm trying to see if I have frontmatter, code:

```
---
title: Sample Post
date: 2019-04-01
fooId:
---
```

is it possible to set a default value for `fooId`? If I live it empty in the markdown file I get:

> Cannot query field "fooId" on type "MdxFrontmatter".
>
> If you don't expect "youTubeId" to exist on the type "MdxFrontmatter"
> it is most likely a typo. However, if you expect "youTubeId" to exist
> there are a couple of solutions to common problems:
>
> - If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node/gatsby-config, please try a restart of your development
>   server.
> - You want to optionally use your field "fooId" and right now it is not used anywhere.
>
> It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want
> to use optional fields.

### Attempt

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = [
    'type MarkdownRemark implements Node { frontmatter: Frontmatter }',
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: 'Frontmatter',
      fields: {
        tags: {
          type: '[String!]',
          resolve(source) {
            const { fooId } = source
            if (fooId === null) return 'foo'
            return fooId
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  ]
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

When I implement the above code I still get the same error in the terminal. Is there a way in *gatsby-node.js* I can default `fooId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type MdxFrontmatter implements Node {
      fooId: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Is not a "default" value *per se* as you mention but using type definitions you are able to customize the expected outcome of the Node when fetched. By default, all (mostly) the values are set as [non-nullable](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/basics/using-nullability-in-graphql/) (in the case above as `String!`). Using the previous type definition, you are setting the `fooId` as a nullable value, meaning that is not required, without the exclamation mark, `!`, what represents the nullability/non-nullability, allowing the `fooId` to be empty.

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to point out that if you use `exports.sourceNodes` in Gatsby 4.19.2:

```
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type MdxFrontmatter implements Node {
      fooId: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

you'll get a deprecation warning which was [originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73158112/3) and to prevent this issue you should use `createSchemaCustomization`:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type MdxFrontmatter implements Node {
      fooId: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```